# #1062 - Duplicate entry for key PRIMARY

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter on my instagram member site.

When I am trying to login in my page for first time it insert the **id** in database, but when I am logging out and clear my session, and try to login again, I get an error:

> internal server error

This is my log error in CodeIgniter:

```
INFO - 2016-12-21 20:47:00 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-12-21 20:47:00 --> Curl class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.
ERROR - 2016-12-21 20:47:00 --> Query error: Duplicate entry '1962377392' for key 'PRIMARY' - Invalid query: INSERT INTO `instagram` (`id`, `cookies`, `useragent`, `device_id`, `poin`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (1962377392, 'ds_user_id=1962377392; expires=Tue, 21-Mar-2017 13:47:00 GMT; Max-Age=7776000;csrftoken=F2Fp1QNOuUgHiI5CViajxBIGbsMtQtVe; expires=Wed, 20-Dec-2017 13:47:00 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/;mid=WFqH1AABAAF38OrHQZq5zamd0q2_; expires=Tue, 16-Dec-2036 13:47:00 GMT; Max-Age=630720000;ds_user=akuuntukkamu; expires=Tue, 21-Mar-2017 13:47:00 GMT; Max-Age=7776000;sessionid=IGSCdf7135cf1f12077c510f35ec09282c3dd788e2f4ff528f853ac568decaac3a8e%3AYyOpVdd67K5vajF2sNgjdfiktjX0M4Lg%3A%7B%22_auth_user_id%22%3A1962377392%2C%22_platform%22%3A1%2C%22_auth_user_hash%22%3A%22%22%2C%22asns%22%3A%7B%22108.168.197.83%22%3A36351%2C%22time%22%3A1482328020%7D%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1482328020.533396%2C%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_token%22%3A%221962377392%3AZWU6rOTIIcRFVtSxnaRcW9veaG9fxO2g%3A22f0a849d9858c559db32062a4b4aa0d59a965213f4c4a182ea63256ef32b2a9%22%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%7D; expires=Tue, 21-Mar-2017 13:47:00 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/;', 'Instagram 6.22.0 Android (11/1.5.3; 240; 480x800; samsung; SM-N9000; SM-N9000; smdkc210; en_US)', 'android-51b39181ee53eec9', 4, 'myinstagramusername', 'myinstagrampassword')
INFO - 2016-12-21 20:47:00 --> Language file loaded: language/english/db_lang.php
```

And this is my login form and ajax:

```
<?=form_open('users/login', array('class' => 'form-horizontal','id' => 'loginform'))?>
    <div id="salsakp" class="input-group col-sm-12"></div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px" class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
        <?=form_input(array('id' => 'username', 'name' => 'username', 'type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Username Anda', 'required' => 'required'))?>                                 
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px" class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
        <?=form_password(array('id' => 'password', 'name' => 'password', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Kata Sandi', 'required' => 'required'))?>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:30px" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
            <button id="btn-login" type="submit" href="#" class="form-control btn btn-info">Masuk</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<?=form_close()?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#username').focus();
    $("form#loginform").submit(function() {
        if ($('#username').val().length > 3 || $('#password').val.length > 3) {
            var pdata = $(this).serialize();
            var purl = $(this).attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                url: purl,
                data: pdata,
                timeout: false,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(hasil) {
                    $("input").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $("button").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $("#btn-login").html('Masuk');
                    if (hasil.result) {
                        window.location.replace(hasil.redirect);
                        $("#salsakp").html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Berhasil Login, Anda akan dialihkan..</div>')
                    } else $("#salsakp").html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">' + hasil.content + '</div>')
                },
                error: function(a, b, c) {
                    $("input").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $("button").removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $("#btn-login").html('Masuk');
                    $("#salsakp").html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">' + c + '</div>')
                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $("#btn-login").html('Loading..');
                    $("#salsakp").html('');
                    $("button").attr("disabled", "disabled")
                }
            })
        }
        return false
    })
});
</script>
```

And this is my login function

```
public function login(){
    if(!$this->session->userdata('credentials')):
        if(!$this->input->post('username')||!$this->input->post('password')) $ret = json_encode(array('result' => 0, 'content' => 'DSMOS has arrived')); else{
            $this->load->library('curl');
            $get = $this->curl->simple_get('https://www.instagram.com/'.trim($this->input->post('username')).'/');
            if($this->curl->info['http_code']<>200) $ret = json_encode(array('result' => 0, 'content' => 'Username/Password salah..')); else{
                    preg_match('#, "id": "(.*?)", "biography"#',$get,$id);
                    $this->load->model('instaloader');
                if ($this->db->get_where('instagram', array('id' => $id[1]))->num_rows() > 0):
                    $rows = $this->db->get_where('instagram', array('id' => $id[1]))->row();
                    $proccess = $this->instaloader->proccess($rows->useragent, 'accounts/login/', 0, $this->instaloader->hook('{"device_id":"'.$rows->device_id.'","guid":"'.$this->instaloader->guid(1).'","username":"'.trim($this->input->post('username')).'","password":"'.trim($this->input->post('password')).'","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}'));
                    $procc = json_decode($proccess[1]);
                    if($procc->status<>ok) $ret = json_encode(array('result' => 0, 'content' => 'Username/Password salah..')); else{
                        preg_match_all('#Set-Cookie: (.+);#',$proccess[0],$d);$cookie='';
                        for($o=0;$o<count($d[0]);$o++)$cookie.=$d[1][$o].";";
                        $this->db->where('id', $procc->logged_in_user->pk)->update('instagram', array('cookies' => $cookie, 'username' => $procc->logged_in_user->username, 'password' => trim($this->input->post('password'))));   
                        $ret = json_encode(array('result' => 1, 'redirect' => base_url())); 
                        $this->session->set_userdata('credentials', array('device_id' => $rows->device_id, 'useragent' => $rows->useragent, 'user_id' => $procc->logged_in_user->pk, 'cookie' => $cookie)); 
                    }
                else:
                    $this->load->model('instaloader');
                    $dev_id = $this->instaloader->device_id();
                    $user_agent = $this->instaloader->useragent();
                    $proccess = $this->instaloader->proccess($user_agent, 'accounts/login/', 0, $this->instaloader->hook('{"device_id":"'.$dev_id.'","guid":"'.$this->instaloader->guid(1).'","username":"'.trim($this->input->post('username')).'","password":"'.trim($this->input->post('password')).'","Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}'));
                    $procc = json_decode($proccess[1]);
                    if($procc->status<>ok) $ret = json_encode(array('result' => 0, 'content' => 'Username/Password salah..')); else{
                        preg_match_all('#Set-Cookie: (.+);#',$proccess[0],$d);$cookie='';
                        for($o=0;$o<count($d[0]);$o++)$cookie.=$d[1][$o].";";
                        $this->db->insert('instagram', array('id' => $procc->logged_in_user->pk, 'cookies' => $cookie, 'useragent' => $user_agent, 'device_id' => $dev_id, 'poin' => 4, 'username' => $procc->logged_in_user->username, 'password' => trim($this->input->post('password')))); 
                        $ret = json_encode(array('result' => 1, 'redirect' => base_url(), 'content' => 'Berhasil Login,Anda akan dialihkan..')); 
                        $this->session->set_userdata('credentials', array('device_id' => $dev_id, 'useragent' => $user_agent, 'user_id' => $procc->logged_in_user->pk, 'cookie' => $cookie)); }
                endif;  
            }
        }
        $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output($ret);
    else:
        redirect(base_url());
    endif;
}
```

So, how to make the query not duplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect Integer (1962377392) because the structures `int()` is too small in your database, change `int()` to `VARCHAR(128)`

Answer (score 0):

It happens only when auto increment not applied on primary key column. In this case your primary key column should be auto incremented. Check once in your database table structure for overcome from this problem.